# How to get unique values of a dataframe column when there are lists - python

Tags: python, pandas, unique

I have the following dataframe where I would like to print the unique values of the `color` column.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'colors': ['green', 'green', 'purple', ['yellow , red'], 'orange'], 'names': ['Terry', 'Nor', 'Franck', 'Pete', 'Agnes']})

Output:
           colors   names
0           green   Terry
1           green     Nor
2          purple  Franck
3  [yellow , red]    Pete
4          orange   Agnes
```

`df.colors.unique()` would work fine if there wasn't the `[yellow , red]` row. As it is I keep getting the `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'` error which is understandable.

Is there a way to still get the unique values without taking this row into account?

I tried the followings but none worked:

```py
df = df[~df.colors.str.contains(',', na=False)] # Nothing happens
df = df[~df.colors.str.contains('[', na=False)] # Output: error: unterminated character set at position 0
df = df[~df.colors.str.contains(']', na=False)] # Nothing happens
```

Comment: Ideally this should work, `df.loc[~df.colors.str.contains('[', na=False, regex=False), 'colors'].unique()`

Comment: The above code returns ['green', 'purple', 'orange']

Comment: @I.M. do you actually want the values inside the list also if they are unique or you want to ignore them?

Comment: For some reasons I also get the ```error: unterminated character set at position 0``` @MahendraSingh

Comment: @vb_rises I could do with ignoring them however the ideal would be to have the unique values of the column even when they are in a list format.

Comment: @MahendraSingh It works perfectly with the example I posted her,e however when I try it on the bigger dataframe I'm working with it goes back to saying that ```TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If values are lists check it by `isinstance` method:

```
#changed sample data
df = pd.DataFrame({'colors': ['green', 'green', 'purple', ['yellow' , 'red'], 'orange'], 
                   'names': ['Terry', 'Nor', 'Franck', 'Pete', 'Agnes']})

df = df[~df.colors.map(lambda x : isinstance(x, list))]
print (df)
   colors   names
0   green   Terry
1   green     Nor
2  purple  Franck
4  orange   Agnes
```

Your solution should be changed with casting to strings and `regex=False` parameter:

```
df = df[~df.colors.astype(str).str.contains('[', na=False, regex=False)] 
print (df)
   colors   names
0   green   Terry
1   green     Nor
2  purple  Franck
4  orange   Agnes
```

Also if want all unique values included lists for pandas 0.25+:

```
s = df.colors.map(lambda x : x if isinstance(x, list) else [x]).explode().unique().tolist()
print (s)
['green', 'purple', 'yellow', 'red', 'orange']
```

Answer (score 2):

Let us using `type`

```
df.colors.apply(lambda x : type(x)!=list)
0     True
1     True
2     True
3    False
4     True
Name: colors, dtype: bool
```

Answer (score 1):

### Changes Input Sample

The input specified had a string which was a list(as specified by the poster), hence converted into a list of strings.

```
# Required Import
from ast import literal_eval

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'colors': ['green', 'green', 'purple', "['yellow' , 'red']", 'orange'], 
    'names': ['Terry', 'Nor', 'Franck', 'Pete', 'Agnes']
})
```

### Perform literal_eval. For more info check-out [literal_eval](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval)

Literal eval in order to covert string to actual list only where there is a list as string

```
list_records = df.colors.str.contains('[', na=False, regex=False)
df.loc[list_records, 'colors'] = df.loc[list_records, 'colors'].apply(literal_eval)
```

### Unique Colors

Works with pandas >= 0.25

```
df.explode('colors')['colors'].unique()
```

Gives

```
['green', 'purple', 'yellow', 'red', 'orange']
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming each of the values in your dataframe are important, here's a technique I frequently use to "unpack lists":

```
import re

def unlock_list_from_string(string, delim=','):
    """
    lists are stored as strings (in csv files) ex. '[1,2,3]'
    this function unlocks that list
    """
    if type(string)!=str:
        return string

    # remove brackets
    clean_string = re.sub('\[|\]', '', string)
    unlocked_string = clean_string.split(delim)
    unlocked_list = [x.strip() for x in unlocked_string]
    return unlocked_list

all_colors_nested = df['colors'].apply(unlock_list_from_string)
# unnest
all_colors = [x for y in all_colors_nested for x in y ]

print(all_colors)
# ['green', 'green', 'purple', 'yellow', 'red', 'orange']
```

Comment: Your method seems to be very interesting and works really well here but I tried it on the dataframe I'm actually working with (which is a very big dataframe) and it unfortunately fails. I'll keep it for more 'normal' sized dataframe though.

Comment: What's the error you're receiving? (I use this solution on large dataframes too)

Comment: The following one: ```IOPub data rate exceeded.
The notebook server will temporarily stop sending output
to the client in order to avoid crashing it.
To change this limit, set the config variable
`--NotebookApp.iopub_data_rate_limit`.```

Comment: Ah, your dataframe is *very* very big. You might consider operating in chunks.